# @parameters method is executed before @beforeclass method

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I'm using "parametrized" feature of junit 4 and I noticed that @parameters method is executed before @beforeclass method. This is creating a problem for me because the parameters i'm passing to the test cases via @parameters depends on the code initialize in the @beforeclass method. For example

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class TestOtherClass {

    String argument;
    private static boolean initializeThis;

    public TestOtherClass(String parameter) throws Exception {
        argument=parameter;
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void doSetup() {
        System.out.println("Doing setup before class...");
        initializeThis=true; // true or false, based on some condition
    }

    @Test
    public void otherTest() {
        System.out.println("Other test: " + argument);
    }

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> getData(){
        System.out.println("Inside parameter");
        String addThis;
        if(initializeThis)
            addThis="adding true";
        else
            addThis="adding false";

        Object[] para1 = new Object[]{"First parameter :: " + addThis};
        Object[] para2 = new Object[]{"Second parameter :: " + addThis};

        Collection<Object[]> classNames = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        classNames.add(para1);
        classNames.add(para2);
        return classNames;
    }
}
```

Now, I'm initializing variable "initializeThis" to true in @beforeclass method but (surprisingly) when I executed the test case it prints

```
Other test: First parameter :: adding false
Other test: Second parameter :: adding false
```

That is something not expected.
My question is; is there any way to execute the @beforeclass method before @parameters, can we do this is in junit 4?

Comment: perhaps pass supplier functions for the parameters that can retrieve the fields later

Answer (score 6):

I would use just plain old java static {..}  initializer instead of @BeforeClass, e.g.:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class TestOtherClass {

    String argument;
    private static boolean initializeThis;

    public TestOtherClass(String parameter) throws Exception {
        argument=parameter;
    }

    static {
        doSetup();
    }

    // @BeforeClass
    public static void doSetup() {
        System.out.println("Doing setup before class...");
        initializeThis=true; // true or false, based on some condition
    }

    @Test
    public void otherTest() {
        System.out.println("Other test: " + argument);
    }

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> getData(){
        System.out.println("Inside parameter");
        String addThis;
        if(initializeThis)
            addThis="adding true";
        else
            addThis="adding false";

        Object[] para1 = new Object[]{"First parameter :: " + addThis};
        Object[] para2 = new Object[]{"Second parameter :: " + addThis};

        Collection<Object[]> classNames = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        classNames.add(para1);
        classNames.add(para2);
        return classNames;
    }
}
```

Only drawback I know is that classes inherited from this won't be able to override static initializer, while @BeforeClass gives some freedom in this aspect;

Answer (score 4):

This is old question but I had the same issue recently. It strikes me that none of the solutions seem to go for the most obvious workaround - calling the @BeforeClass method in the @Parameters method. The latter is static and executed only once - before any of the tests have been run. So, it is for all intents and purposes a @BeforeClass method even though it is not annotated as such. More details can be found here: http://feraldeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2013/12/beforeclass-and-parametrized-junit-tests.html

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work if your test requires something like `@ClassRule public static TemporaryFolder folder = new TemporaryFolder();` as even the ClassRule gets initialized after the method annotated with @Parameters (https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/issues/527)

Answer (score 1):

JUnit creates a `Runner` for each item in the parameter list, a `Runner` is what encapsulates the test method. So the `@Parameters` will always get executed before the @BeforeClass.

However, you can combine the @Parameterized with [Assume](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assume.html). You always include all of the parameters in your list, whether or not you intend executing it. Then in the test method, add the `assumeTrue()` which tests against the `initializeThis` value.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class TestOtherClassAssume {
  private final String argument;
  private final boolean initializeThisTest;
  private static boolean initializeThis;

  @Parameters
  public static Collection<Object[]> getData(){
    System.out.println("Inside parameter");

    return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
      { false, "First" },
      { true, "Second" },
    });
  }

  public TestOtherClassAssume(boolean initializeThisTest, String argument) {
    this.initializeThisTest = initializeThisTest;
    this.argument = argument;
  }

  @BeforeClass
  public static void doSetup() {
    System.out.println("Doing setup before class...");
    initializeThis = true; // true or false, based on some condition
  }

  @Test
  public void otherTest() {
    Assume.assumeTrue(initializeThis == initializeThisTest);
    System.out.println("Other test: " + argument);
  }
}
```

The output from this is:

```
Inside parameter
Doing setup before class...
Other test: Second
```

Answer (score 0):

However, this does not work with TestSuites.
Given

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class TogglableParameterizedTest {
    static boolean useAllParameters = false;

    int parameter;

    public TogglableParameterizedTest(int parameter) {
        super();
        this.parameter = parameter;
    }
    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> getTestParameters() {
        List<Object[]> parameters = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        if(useAllParameters) {
            parameters.add(new Object[] { 1 });
            parameters.add(new Object[] { 2 });
            parameters.add(new Object[] { 3 });
        }
        else {
            parameters.add(new Object[] { 1 });
        }
        return parameters;
    }
    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("parameter=" + parameter);
    }
}
```

This does not work:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ TogglableParameterizedTest.class })
public class NonWorkingTestSuite1 {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void toggle() {
        System.out.println("sets flag to late!");
    }

}
```

The output is

```
sets flag to late!
parameter=1
```

Nor that:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ TogglableParameterizedTest.class }) 
public class NonWorkingTestSuite2 {
    static {
        System.out.println("sets flag still to late");
        TogglableParameterizedTest.useAllParameters = true;
    }
}
```

The output is "parameter=1". So the static initializer not executed at all.
I found the following workaround.
Extend "Suite" and insert the static initializer there:

```
public class TogglingSuite extends Suite {

    static {
        System.out.println("sets flag early enough!");
        TogglableParameterizedTest.useAllParameters = true;
    }

    public TogglingSuite(Class<?> klass, Class<?>[] suiteClasses)
        throws InitializationError {
        super(klass, suiteClasses);
    }

    public TogglingSuite(Class<?> klass, List<Runner> runners)
        throws InitializationError {
        super(klass, runners);
    }

    public TogglingSuite(Class<?> klass, RunnerBuilder builder)
            throws InitializationError {
        super(klass, builder);
    }

    public TogglingSuite(RunnerBuilder builder, Class<?> klass,
            Class<?>[] suiteClasses) throws InitializationError {
        super(builder, klass, suiteClasses);
    }

    public TogglingSuite(RunnerBuilder builder, Class<?>[] classes)
            throws InitializationError {
        super(builder, classes);
    }
}
```

and use it in your test suite:

```
@RunWith(TogglingSuite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ TogglableParameterizedTest.class })
public class WorkingTestSuite {

}
```

The output is

```
sets flag early enough!
parameter=1
parameter=2
parameter=3
```

Now it works.