# Problems with execution of JUnit4 TestCases and TestSuite

Tags: java, junit, junit4, system-properties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [@parameters method is executed before @beforeclass method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430859/parameters-method-is-executed-before-beforeclass-method)

I am facing some trouble with JUnit 4 TestsUites and Parameterized Tests.

In my Suite I want to set a SystemProperty like this:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ParameterizedTestCase.class })
public class TestSuite {

     @BeforeClass
     public static void setUpSuite() {
        System.out.println("suite");
        System.setProperty("propertyToSet", "propertyToSet");
     }

}
```

In the ParameterizedTestCase I declared the generateParams() to print the Property like this:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ParameterizedTestCase{
     @Parameters
     public static Collection<Object[]> generateParams() {
     System.out.println("Parameter: " + System.getProperty("propertyToSet"));
     }

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        //doSometing
    }
}
```

The Output i get is as follows:

```
Parameter: null
suite
```

So the Methods are invoked in the wrong order.  I thought, that the BeforeClass of the Suite is invoked before all TestClasses.

How can I fix this problem. I need to set a Parameter in the Suite, which will be used by several TestCases. But the TestCases don't know from which Suite they are invoked. So I prefer something like a Systemproperty.

Thanks for your Help

Kirschmichel